# How not always pass "$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization" in run function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't want to pass the Bearer token in every http request, so to automate it I did the following:

```
 angular.module('projectApp').run(function ($http, $rootScope, $location) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');
 }
```

But when there is a page that don't need authentication, the header will be passed too. There is a way to optionally don't pass this header(but pass it as default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that header to undefined for a particular request like this:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', {headers: { 'Authorization ': undefined }}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I am no 100% convinced that it is the best solution. It will depend on the amount of request that you have with this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to select in what requests add the Authorization header, like this:

Config :

```
app.config([ '$httpProvider',   function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');
} ]);
```

Service :

```
app.service('APIInterceptor', [function() {
    var service = this;

    service.request = function(config) {
        config.headers.YOUR_HEADER= YOUR_HEADERS_VALUE;
        return config;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I have tried to do that, but the result was the same when I was passing the default header on angular.module('projectApp').run